# Tesseract command line interface: Get recognition confidence per character

Tags: tesseract

When using Tesseract C API, it is possible to iterate over the recognized characters, getting their bounding boxes and their recognition confidence.

I've found out already how to get the bounding boxes using the Tesseract CLI, it is done by adding **makebox** at the end of the command. The problem is that it does not contain the recognition confidence.

Is there some way for telling Tesseract CLI to also output the confidence of each character?

Comment: did you get any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Below is an API example from [tesseract github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample#getcomponentimages-example).

### GetComponentImages example

```
Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
  tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
  api->Init(NULL, "eng");
  api->SetImage(image);
  Boxa* boxes = api->GetComponentImages(tesseract::RIL_TEXTLINE, true, NULL, NULL);
  printf("Found %d textline image components.\n", boxes->n);
  for (int i = 0; i < boxes->n; i++) {
    BOX* box = boxaGetBox(boxes, i, L_CLONE);
    api->SetRectangle(box->x, box->y, box->w, box->h);
    char* ocrResult = api->GetUTF8Text();
    int conf = api->MeanTextConf();
    fprintf(stdout, "Box[%d]: x=%d, y=%d, w=%d, h=%d, confidence: %d, text: %s",
                    i, box->x, box->y, box->w, box->h, conf, ocrResult);
  }
```

The `fprintf()` included to print the box and confidence info.

Hope this help.

**EDIT:**

To get confidence (`conf`) value as well as bounding box (`left`, `top`, `width`, `height`) from CLI, set `tesseract` output to `tsv` format. The following is a sample command with output file name as `test.tsv`.

```
C:\> tesseract test.tif test -l eng tsv
```

Here is the `tsv` output file viewed by Excel.
[image]

You may refer to this [tesseract wiki](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage#tsv-output-currently-available-in-305-dev-in-master-branch-on-github) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the API example. I need some way to do it with the CLI, as I work in Windows. Compiling Tesseract in Windows for working with its API is a real headache

Comment: @SomethingSomething Agreed that it's not easier to get `tesseract` complied. With the updated Answer with `CLI command` to ease the shell command execution, hope it would help if applicable to your case. Please check.

Comment: @thewayweare, thank you. The problem with the TSV is that it only outputs word confidences and not single char confidences. In Tesseract API, with the iterator level, you can get the confidence also per char, which is what I need